# what packages does an `apt` source.list provide?

Tags: debian, package-management, apt, apt-cache

Is there a way to tell what packages are provided by an `/etc/apt/sources.list*` entry?

I see that `apt-cache policy '*'` lists all packages provided by all sources, which could be parsed, but that's... humongous. I suppose one could also look in `/var/lib/apt/lists`. Anything simpler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the list of packages provided by `main`, `contrib`, `non-free`, `security` repositories and components you need to parse the files under `/var/lib/apt/lists`. E,g:

```
grep Package: /var/lib/apt/lists/deb.debian.org_debian_dists_buster_contrib_binary-amd64_Package
```

Comment: yes, I mentioned "look in /var/lib/apt/lists" in the post...